# buttons not working properly in jq dialog content (two ways of closing jquery dialog with bootstrap table)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-dialog

I'm working with bootstrap table inside of jquery dialog and having problems with closing dialog and freeing memory. Let me show on demo code:

**Method 1:** [jsFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/udk6hgmp/) Here is the code with two buttons inside dialog content which I use to save or cancel. They are coded with `$.click()` (not by dialog). To see the problem fallow 4 steps:

1. Click first checkbox and accept date
2. Do the same for the second checkbox
3. Uncheck both (date field is empty in both rows)
4. Check again one checkbox and accept date

You will notice now that the date was added into both fields of each row even if didn't click the second one. When I play more like this I can even uncheck both checkboxes with one click.

**Method 2:** [jsFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/udk6hgmp/2/) The same idea, but I use buttons defined in jquery dialog and if you do the same steps from above, you won't notice the problem - it works just fine.

**Question:** I need to use the first method for my own purpose, but what to do to fix this memory problem?

Comment: what does this have to do with a memory leak?

Comment: I'm not English I may use wrong terminology, sorry for my english. I just want to say that somehow it memorizes the last steps (row indexes). Maybe there is something with destroying the dialog, why the second method works fine?

Comment: i think ` $('#submitBtn').click` is being applied many times because a console.log() inside it fires once the first time, and many times after that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a scope problem in your code;
Please try this updated [Fidle](https://jsfiddle.net/udk6hgmp/4/)

```
  var currentRow = null;

 $("#pickdate").datepicker({dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"}).datepicker("setDate",new Date());
$('#table').on('check.bs.table', function (e, row, $el) {

currentRow = row;

     $("#dialog").dialog({
                dialogClass: "no-close tt",
                modal: true,
                title: "Data zamknięcia",
                width:189,
        });


});
```

See fidle for full code

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works! I'm thinking why it has to be done like that? It should take the newest row.id in my demo and there is only one line where i assign the value for the field per time

Comment: @soonic Glad i could help. It might be better mark my answer as correct to help others

Comment: It was driving me crazy till now. I haven't noticed that you have also changed the brackets for `check.bs.table` function so those two buttons (cancel and ok) went outside of it. The problem with `row` was gone but then I noticed that is submitting a few times when working with other values. Eh... now it's really working :)) My first comment is no longer valid. I understand now :) Thanks again!